# Is the interaction of the electron w/ a photon in the double-slit experiment simply distorts the experience & not the consciousness of the observer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, double-slit-experiment

We know that in the Young double-slit experiment, the quantum interpretation of the experiment is based on the fact that an individual particle finds itself in a superimposed state following the crossing of the slits. We can interpret this fact by saying that the particle passed through the two slits at the same time.
With the experiment of Frabboni, the net result of the experiment with electrons is that we detect that the electron passes either in the right slot or in the left slot, but then the figure of interference disappears: the electron is no longer in a superimposed state because of the interaction with a photon for a measurement (whether the electron is detected or not). The interaction of the electron with a photon at one of the slits causes a "collapse of the wave function" and of the superimposed state. There is no way to know which side the quantum is on without eliminating the interference phenomenon.

We can hear some scientist say that it is the consciousness of the observer that change the state of the electron. But isn't it simply the photon that change the experiment without the need to extrapolate to other solutions?

Comment: "the fact that an individual particle finds itself in a superimposed state " This is not a fact but an interpretation, to which I do not subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's nothing to do with our consciousness. I don't think I've heard any actual physicists say it's our consciousness either, at least in more recent times (maybe near the beginning of QM there were some, I'm not sure). In fact, I've seen many physicists get very annoyed at this misinterpretation get repeated, because it leads to all the quantum woo stuff that people like deepak chopra try to market